# [SCSS]Fonts are not loading in my machine/browser but works on other machines

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, vite

Fonts don't get loaded if the paths are relative. Absolute path works just fine though.

```
//styles.scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
  src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Medium';
  src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine on other machines. But it's giving me error 404 resource not found when on all my browsers. So I tried changing the paths to this:

```
//styles.scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
  src: url('./src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Medium';
  src: url('./src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
  src: url('./src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
}
```

And it suddenly works on my local machine...of course it didn't work on the other machines. Any idea what's wrong with my machine?

Tried checking if the fonts are corrupted. Tried changing the paths...but no hope.

UPDATE:

```
server: {
port: 8000,
strictPort: true,
host: true,
origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'}
```

changing the origin of vite.config.ts from http://0.0.0.0:8000 to 127.0.0.1 suddenly works...but i still don't understand why it works for others but not for me

Answer (score 0):

.. stands for father folder and . Stands for the folder itself. If you are trying to use absolute addressing you can not use dot.

Also if you are using react, You can configure your application to support importing modules using absolute paths.
jsconfig.json file for a JavaScript project. You can create the file if it doesn't already exist:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": "src"
    }
    ,"include": ["src"]
}
```

See react docs here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports